# Can't open drive marked as System in Disk Management in W7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-management

Reinstalled Windows 7 64bit recently on my new HDD. Now one of my drives I use as storage is marked with status "Healthy (System, Active, Primary Partition)" and I can't open it to view the contents as Right-Click -> Open is grey'd out and it doesn't show up in "My Computer".

What do I do to remedy this without losing what's on this drive?

Comment: "can't open" does not tell us much. More details please. Use the edit feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Right Clicking the drive in Disk Management and assigning it a drive letter